# Codeigniter doesn't return first submit name from multi form page

Tags: javascript, php, forms, codeigniter

I have a multi form page in view:

```
 <?php echo form_open("account"); ?>
 // input fields
 <input type="submit" name="change-password" value="Change Password"/>
 </form> 

<?php echo form_open("account"); ?>
 // input fields
 <input type="submit" name="change-email" value="Change Email"/>
 </form>
```

And in controller I'm checking:

```
if (!empty($_POST['change-password']))
    {
       // 
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['change-email']))
    {
        //
    }
```

`$_POST['change-password']` is always `null`.

So I tried to switch them places and even added third form. Whatever I do, I can't get submit `name` from FIRST submit form, but can get them from second, and third.

**UPDATE:**
I have found the bug.

I didn't mention this, but my submit buttons on forms have an id="submit-btn"
and JavaScript that prevent double submit is making all the trouble:

```
$("form").one('submit', function() {
    $('#submit-btn').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

And I don't understand why, but this is another question.

Comment: why you need two form ?

Comment: @Boby - cuz that's how he rolls, I've had up to 15 forms on one page.  No problem.

Comment: First off I would avoid the `-` in filed names, just bad mojo from that, Underline is much safer.   Secondly your not trying to get the first form when submitting the second one right?  I dont use CI's crappy template system, but did you try naming the other form something else.

Comment: I agree, dash, should be avoided, tested - nothing changed. I have tried Boby's ( already deleted answer ) and it work. So there is something wrong in my code. Will debug and post an answer.

Comment: you need to change your form name like change_email. use _ instead of -.

Answer (score 0):

Add unique hidden fields for both forms and check that fields name in method (here post) in controller.

```
 <?php echo form_open("account"); ?>
 // input fields
 <input type="hidden" name="first_form" value="first_form"/>
 <input type="submit" name="change-password" value="Change Password"/>
 </form> 

 <?php echo form_open("account"); ?>
// input fields
<input type="hidden" name="second_form" value="second_form"/>
<input type="submit" name="change-email" value="Change Email"/>
</form>


if ($_POST['first_form'])
{
   // inside first form
}

if ($_POST['second_form'])
{
    // inside second form
}
```